# Why does a non-advertised shortcut created within the startup folder, does not auto start the application upon reboot?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2015

I have an basic msi installer, created with Installshield 2015, that created 2 advertised shortcuts within the startup folder 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp'.

This creates also 2 entries within the Startup Apps pane within system settings:
[image]

I got complaints from our EQA department, that the application name and vendor name is not present in this list.

I thaught I found the solution by setting these 2 shortcuts to non-advertised within my basic msi project. At first sight, this seemed to work fine. The 2 entries within the Startup Apps list were created with the application name and vendor name BUT... when I reboot my system, the 2 applications do not auto-start anymore upon login.

***Any idea why the auto start works for advertised shortcuts (but then they are not shown property within the startup app list), and not for non-advertised shortcuts?***